# Resource already exists exception, when tried to run elasticsearch in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, elasticsearch

What I do:

1. **Download** elastic search from [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch)
2. **Run** this on my ubuntu (20.04) - bin/elasticsearch
3. **Add** `"elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master"` to my composer.json file in laravel's project directory
4. **Run** `composer update`
5. **Run** this command to put elasticsearch conf. file into config directory `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Elasticquent\ElasticquentServiceProvider"`

6.**Change** `default_index` in this conf. file, so at the end, it looks like:

```
   <?php
    
    return array(
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Custom Elasticsearch Client Configuration
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This array will be passed to the Elasticsearch client.
        | See configuration options here:
        |
        | http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_configuration.html
        */
    
        'config' => [
            'hosts'     => ['localhost:9200'],
            'retries'   => 1,
        ],
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Default Index Name
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This is the index name that Elasticquent will use for all
        | Elasticquent models.
        */
    
        'default_index' => 'posts',
    
    );
```

7.In **Models/Post.php** add

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait; // this

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use ElasticquentTrait; // this

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'category_id'];

    protected $mappingProperties = array( // this
        'title' => array(
             'type' => 'text',
             'analyzer' => 'standard'
         )
     );

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }


}

?>
```

8.Then in **routes/web.php** (just for the test) add:

```
Route::get('/search', function () {
    Post::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);

    Post::putMapping($ignoreConflicts = true);

    Post::addAllToIndex();
});
```

9.**Finally** when I open localhost:8000/search I got this error on the screen:

> Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index
> [posts/ph2xUqdFSomr0GfIYnDhDA] already
> exists","index_uuid":"ph2xUqdFSomr0GfIYnDhDA","index":"posts"}],"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index
> [posts/ph2xUqdFSomr0GfIYnDhDA] already
> exists","index_uuid":"ph2xUqdFSomr0GfIYnDhDA","index":"posts"},"status":400}

I did research, but at the moment I can't find anything to guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Change your route to:

```
Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'index']);

//Use only one of the routes below

Route::get('/search/{q}', [PostController:class,'search']); // Get with 'q' as URL
Route::post('/search', [PostController:class,'search']); // OR Post with 'q' as parameter
```

Then move your logic to the `PostController`:

```
function index(){
    Post::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);

    Post::putMapping($ignoreConflicts = true);

    Post::addAllToIndex();

    return('your_view'); // Optional
}

function search(Request $request){
    
    $data = $request->all() //Assuming that you send query as "q"

    $posts = Post::searchByQuery(['match' => ['title' => $data->q]]);

    return $posts;
}
```

When you land at the main `/` route the table will be indexed and then when you hit `/search` route this should now work.

Comment: Both commands return `Unknown parameters provided`

Comment: Hey, sorry I misinterpreted your question with Ruby. Have you tried moving the logic written in the ```web.php``` to the controller and calling the route again?

Comment: Check my updated answer